# SQL sum money with currency

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, varchar2

[image]

If I want a query that displays the number of customers living in Penang and also the sum of their income, how should I do it?

```
SELECT COUNT(Cust_state), SUM(Cust_income)
FROM Customer
WHERE Cust_state = ‘Penang’;
```

This would not work as the values in Cust_income has a preceding $.

EDIT: The datatype for Cust_income is varchar2.

Comment: What is the data type of `cust_income`?  Tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not images. (Copy-and-paste...)

Comment: @jarlh this is just my exercise question, meaning that's all I got and I don't any have sample table data.

Comment: @jade . . . `number` is fine in Oracle, but it is not a standard data type.  `numeric` is standard.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff ah i see.. thanks for pointing out! I'm actually new to sql so I haven't fully grasp the concepts.. btw could you add another closing parenthesis at your answer like this `NUMERIC(20, 4)))` as I could not edit it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are storing the value as a *string*, then you should fix the data!  Don't store numeric values as strings -- you can always add the currency for output purposes.

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(Cust_state),
       SUM(CAST(REPLACE(Cust_income, '$', '') as NUMERIC(20, 4))
FROM Customer
WHERE Cust_state = 'Penang';
```

Use whatever type is appropriate for the income.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply appropriate format mask to `TO_NUMBER` function, then you could do as follows (sample data in lines #1 - 4; query begins at line #5):

```
SQL> with customer (cust_id, cust_income) as
  2    (select 1, '$1000' from dual union all
  3     select 4, '$1600' from dual
  4    )
  5  select sum(to_number(cust_income, '$9999999999')) sum_income
  6  from customer;

SUM_INCOME
----------
      2600

SQL>
```